# Https connection issue the streamupload (coreservice)

Tags: core-service, https

I'm really stuck trying to connect to the stream upload service via coreservice - Over HTTPS

I'm getting the following error:

> The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'

I can connect to the usual content endpoint (*wsHttp_201501*) the issue i'm having is connecting to the upload service (*streamUpload_basicHttp_201501*)

Here's my config file:

```
<protocolMapping>

  <add scheme="https" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>

</protocolMapping>


<bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">

      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" />

      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">

        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>

      </security>

    </binding>

    <binding name="streamDownload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedResponse" messageEncoding="Mtom" sendTimeout="00:10:00">

      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">

        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>

      </security>

    </binding>

    <binding name="streamUpload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedRequest" messageEncoding="Mtom" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">

      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">

        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>

      </security>

    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>



  <wsHttpBinding>

    <binding name="wsHttp" transactionFlow="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">

      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760"/>

      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">

        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>

      </security>

    </binding>

  </wsHttpBinding>



</bindings>

<client>

  <endpoint name="wsHttp_201501" address="https://serv_name.com/webservices/CoreService201501.svc/wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService">

    <identity>

      <dns value="serv_name.com/" />

    </identity>

  </endpoint>

  <endpoint name="streamUpload_basicHttp_201501" address="https://serv_name.com/webservices/CoreService201501.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamUpload_basicHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.IStreamUpload">

    <identity>

      <dns value="serv_name.com/" />

    </identity>

  </endpoint>        

</client>
```

Answer (score 2):

For HTTPS, the WCF binding security mode should be set to `Transport` instead of `TransportCredentialOnly`

Comment: Afraid this has no impact - still the same error.

Comment: Did you change both client and server configs?

Comment: Guess this is fixed with setting up right contract filter in stream_upload_basichttp and using latest 8.2 core service dll.